# problem with sandcastle generated .chm help file?

Tags: c#-2.0, sandcastle

i have generated a help file for my project using sandcastle,a .chm file. but the content can only seen when i open it in my machine. i have gave that file to several friends none of them can see the content of the file. what is the wrong?? how can i resolve it?? any problem with my configurations??
please help me guys!!!

regards,
rangana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is probably marked as "From the Internet" and therefore seen as possibly dangerous by the internet explorer trying to display the file.

Right-Click the file, and click the *Unblock* button on the *General* property page.

Comment: hi.. i cant understand your answer. can u please elaborate a bit. i'm using sandcastle for the first time.

Comment: I just guess that you sent the file to your friends' computers through some kind of network. Newer windows versions mark files from network/internet as possibly malicious. Therefore, your friends have to tell windows that the file is ok, doing so in the CHM file's property dialog.

I recently had a similar problem with a CHM file downloaded from a network share. I could open the file, but the CHM viewer did not display any content.

Comment: yes that is exactly the thing happened with me. what should i do to this problem? any solutions?? this is very important. please help me.

Comment: hi, problem is solved. i've gave my friends a copy of the file using my pendrive.. :)
thank you very much for the help!!!